# Keep widget central forever after inserting an spaceritem

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, layout, desktop-application

I want to customize a titlebar:

```cpp
class TitlebarWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
   public:
    TitlebarWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr): QWidget(parent) {
        setupUi();
    }
    virtual ~TitlebarWidget();

   private:
    void setupUi(){
        QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
        layout->setSpacing(0);
        layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
  //    layout->addSpacerItem(new QSpacerItem(width(), height(),     
        QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed));

        m_homeButton = new QPushButton(this);
        m_homeButton->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
        m_homeButton->setMinimumWidth(50);
        m_homeButton->setMaximumWidth(50);
        m_homeButton->setText(tr("Home"));
        layout->addWidget(m_homeButton);

        QLabel* label = new QLabel(this);
        label->setText("Titlebar");
        layout->addWidget(label, 0, Qt::AlignCenter);

        m_synButton = new QPushButton(this);
        m_synButton->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
        m_synButton->setMinimumWidth(100);
        m_synButton->setMaximumWidth(100);
        m_homeButton->setText(tr("Sync"));
    }
    QPushButton* m_synButton;
    QPushButton* m_homeButton;
    QPushButton* m_settingButton;
    QRCodeWidget* m_synPhoneWidget;
};
```

The titlebar is as follows:
[image]
`Home` button is covered by the three circles at top-left corner, so I insert an spacer-item at the beginning:

```cpp
layout->addSpacerItem(new QSpacerItem(width(), height(), QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed));
```

And the titlebar is like:
[image]

I found the text 'Titlebar' was obviously deviated from the center, but I want keep it central. who can help me with a workaround or a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Use `layout->addSpacing()` instead and `addStretch` works for me.